# how can i bind igniteUI grid with data table(oracle)?

Tags: jquery, html, oracle, datatable, ignite-ui

I am creating html5 application in which I want to get data table from oracle DB like we do in simple asp.net application and bind that data table with igniteUI grid. Please tell me how can i do this in html5 application and bind it to ignite ui datagrid.

Reason for using HTML5 is I want to make responsive application that can be used in all platforms (desktop, web, mobile).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view there is no difference at all if you will be using HTML5 or not for this purpose. The ignite UI will provide you with a JS implementation of the grid. You would just need to create a server-side ASPX code which will return a JSON array on request (so that that the interaction with Oracle DB to be performed on server-side). And the front-end code will be responsible for proper rendering in desktop / mobile devices.